# Would the Copa del Rey change its name for a queen?

Tags: football, trivia, terminology

If a princess such as Leonor, Princess of Asturias succeeds to the Spanish throne, would the name of the [Copa del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_del_Rey) change to become the Copa de la Reina?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The *[Copa del Rey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_del_Rey)* was originally named in honour of Alfonso XIII, and is now a generic king's cup.

The *[Copa de la Reina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_de_la_Reina_de_F%C3%BAtbol)* is the cup awarded for the corresponding women's competition. There does not appear to be a naming honour for this particular cup,  and it appears to be a generic queen's cup, named for symmetry reasons.

Comment: did not know that the Copa del Rey name was in honor of Alfonso XIII. Makes sense. Is there a specific queen that the Copa de la Reina is named after or is it just that?

Comment: For *Copa d. Rey* it was originally Alfonso, went through a number of changes based on who was the boss at any given time, and back to a generic "king's cup" as now. It seems like the naming was based on symmetry, since there are *Copa d. l. Reina* for  a number of sports. The might be a nominative honouring to Sofia (queen to Juan Carlos I) because she happened to be queen at the time, but it seems more like it's a generic "queen's cup" than belonging to any specific queen.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

**The official name** of the competition, according to [the Royal Spanish Federation of Football (RFEF)'s regulations](http://cdn1.sefutbol.com/sites/default/files/reglamento_general_2016-2017_web.pdf)
 [PDF], **is "*Campeonato de España*"**, with a trailing *"Copa de S.M. el Rey"* for the male competition and *"Copa de S.M. la Reina"* for the female competition. And an additional *"de Fútbol Sala"* for the corresponding indoor football competitions.

In the past, the cup has received [several different trailing names](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copa_del_Rey#Historia), depending on the current political system and Head of State:

- *Copa de Su Majestad el Rey* (1903-1930).
- *Copa de Su Excelencia el Presidente de la República* (1931-1936).
- *Torneo Nacional de Fútbol* (1939).
- *Copa de Su Excelencia el Generalísimo* (1940-1976).
- *Copa de Su Majestad el Rey* (1976-).

However, **the RFEF is a private organization**, and AFAIK **it gets to choose the name of the competitions** it hosts.

So, in the event of Spain switching from a king to a queen (or something else), a number of possibilities open:

- Mixed-gender teams are a thing by then, and so the distinction "*Rey* = male cup, *Reina* = female cup" is not in place anymore.

  - The RFEF decides that the name "Copa del Rey" has been in use for too long for a change to be well received: **the name is not changed**.
  - The RFEF decides that the name "Copa de la Reina" makes more sense: **the name is changed**.
  - The RFEF decides the topic is way too controversial to take a stance: **the name is dropped**.
- Male and female competitions are still held separately, and Rey / Reina are still used to differentiate them:

  - The RFEF decides that the competition should be named against the Head of State, i.e. the Queen now: **the names are changed, using Reina for the male cup and Rey for the female cup.**
  - The RFEF decides that the female competition deserves the additional attention given by being the main cup: **the name is not changed**.
  - The RFEF decides the topic is way too controversial to take a stance: **the name is dropped**.
- The "democratic monarchy" system is not in place anymore (out of your scope, but still a possibility):

  - The RFEF decides to keep "Copa del Rey" either out of tradition or to make a political statement: **the name is not changed**.
  - The RFEF decides to go with the ages: **the name is changed**, probably to *"Copa de la Presidencia"* or the like, **or just completely dropped** in favor of plain old *"Campeonato de España"*.

As I said, it depends.

My personal opinion is that, by the time Leonor could be crowned, this would be a non-issue.